# Formula to convert matrix to rows in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to concatenate rows of a matrix in a spreadsheet, which I've got from an `importhtml` call.

For example, if I have a 3x3 table:

```
A   B   C
D   E   F
G   H   I
```

I would like a command/function to convert it a row like so:

```
A B C D E F G H I
```

The idea is that each line will have a different html form which the same table/data is meant to be extracted. This cannot be done manually each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace **A1:C3** with your `IMPORTHTML` formula:

```
=SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A1:C3),,999^99)),,999^99), " ")
```

[image]

---

if it contains words / spaces:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 SUBSTITUTE(A1:C3, " ", CHAR(127))),,999^99)),,999^99), " "))
```

[image]

Comment: This works, hence the answer is accepted. Would be nice to add some explanations on *how* this works. I don't understand the `QUERY` command here, not the `CHAR(127)`

Comment: CHAR(127) is a character that only looks like empty space. purpose of that double query is to compress everything into one single cell (by doing so as a residue an empty space will be auto-added to each cell) and then we just SPLIT it